# How to estimate whether a given task would have enough memory to run in Java

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I am developing an application that allows users to set the maximum data set size they want me to run their algorithm against

It has become apparent that array sizes around 20,000,000 in size causes an 'out of memory' error. Because I am invoking this via reflection, there is not really a great deal I can do about this.

I was just wondering, is there any way I can check / calculate what the maximum array size could be based on the users heap space settings and therefore validate user entry before running the application?

If not, are there any better solutions?

#### Use Case:

- The user provides a data size they want to run their algorithm against, we generate a scale of numbers to test it against up to the limit they provided.
- We record the time it takes to run and measure the values (in order to work out the o-notation).
- We need to somehow limit the users input so as to not exceed or get this error. Ideally we want to measure n^2 algorithms on as bigger array sizes as we can (which could last in terms of runtime for days) therefore we really don't want it running for 2 days and then failing as it would have been a waste of time.

Comment: Why don't `catch` the error, and let the user know when it occures [and stops invoking the user code]? Isn't it why errors & exceptions are for? :\

Comment: What are the data contained inside your array? Primitive types? Custom objects?

Comment: @TeddyBearFr the data can be anytype, amit - i could do that but then it skews the results we generate which - if they have waited for a while for their application to run could be a waste of time

Comment: @Ricki: Can you describe [with example if possible] required input and output for what you are seeking? The general problem [how much space will a program use?] is unsolveable (equivalent to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), but I suspect you don't face the general problem.

Comment: @amit added a use case, its hard to write the code because its generic, the user implements our interface to generate data of the type their method requires and then we measure how long it takes to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the result of `Runtime.freeMemory()` to estimate the amount of available memory. However, it might be that actually a lot of memory is occupied by unreachable objects, which will be reclaimed by GC soon. So you might actually be able to use more memory than this. You can try invoking the GC before, but this is not guaranteed to do anything.

The second difficulty is to estimate the amount of memory needed for a number given by the user. While it is easy to calculate the size of an ArrayList with so many entries, this might not be all. For example, which objects are stored in this list? I would expect that there is at least one object per entry, so you need to add this memory too. Calculating the size of an arbitrary Java object is much more difficult (and in practice only possible if you know the data structures and algorithms behind the objects). And then there might be a lot of temporary objects creating during the run of the algorithm (for example boxed primitives, iterators, StringBuilders etc.).

Third, even if the available memory is theoretically sufficient for running a given task, it might be practically insufficient. Java programs can get very slow if the heap is repeatedly filled with objects, then some are freed, some new ones are created and so on, due to a large amount of Garbage Collection.

So in practice, what you want to achieve is very difficult and probably next to impossible. I suggest just try running the algorithm and catch the OutOfMemoryError.

Usually, catching errors is something you should not do, but this seems like an occasion where its ok (I do this in some similar cases). You should make sure that as soon as the OutOfMemoryError is thrown, some memory becomes reclaimable for GC. This is usually not a problem, as the algorithm aborts, the call stack is unwound and some (hopefully a lot of) objects are not reachable anymore. In your case, you should probably ensure that the large list is part of these objects which immediately become unreachable in the case of an OOM. Then you have a good chance of being able to continue your application after the error.

However, note that this is not a guarantee. For example, if you have multiple threads working and consuming memory in parallel, the other threads might as well receive an OutOfMemoryError and not be able to cope with this. Also the algorithm needs to support the fact that it might get interrupted at any arbitrary point. So it should make sure that the necessary cleanup actions are executed nevertheless (and of course you are in trouble if those need a lot of memory!).